# How to capture the text of a notification using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, javascript-objects

I have been going across various API and pages but have unable to find a way to capture the content (text content) of web page notification and print it on console. There are ways to create a notification, close it but I am not sure how to capture the text of the notification and print on console using Javascript. Can you please help me get out of this fix?

Comment: What kind of notification do you want to get access to, where does the notification originate from? What code do you currently have?

Comment: We have a mashup API on which we open a webpage. Many a time, the as soon as the webpage opens, there are notification generated(like 400 Bad request). Just wanted to check if we can we capture the notification or print it on console?

Answer (score -1):

The Notifications API is fairly new and it may not work at older browsers. Therefore, you should explicitly verify if the API is supported by the browser or not before showing a message. You can do this by checking if the window object has a property called Notification:

```
if(!window.Notification) {
  console.log('Browser does not support notifications.');
} else {
  // display message here
}
```

On supported platforms, displaying a desktop notification involves two things: requesting permission and creating a new notification to display to the user. [more info](https://attacomsian.com/blog/desktop-notifications-javascript)

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. I validated the same an Notification API is supported by the browser. However, I am still unsure how to capture the content(text content) of the notification. Could you please suggest

Comment: there are many types of APIs available use them